# Realm Object Server + MSSQL / MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, realm, realm-mobile-platform

It is possible to connect between SQL Database and Realm? And how to observe the changes of the SQL database to reflect to the Realm Object Server.

Comment: Well just know that [data connectors are part of the **enterprise** edition of the Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#data-connector). So they are not exactly free.

Answer (score 0):

As @EpicPandaForce said, the Data Connector API is only available in the Enterprise edition. You can read more [here](https://blog.realm.io/making-postgresql-realtime/), [here](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#data-connector) and [here](https://realm.io/pricing/)

As of today (29/08/2017) we have a Data Connector to Postgres that allows you to mirror data between Postgres and Realm. There are plans to support other databases as well, but we don't have a public timeline for those yet. You can reach out to sales@realm.io for more information.

Comment: "There are plans to support other databases as well". You mean for free?

Comment: No, it would still require an enterprise license

Comment: Ok, I hope someday it would be free.

Comment: `someday it would be free` That's unlikely though, because then Realm's devs would starve to death, and nobody wants that, haha.